# Magento Model controller not executing

Tags: php, magento, controller

I'm new to magento development,and I'm trying to add controller for my module but it's not working out with me (404 error messages appears).
here is the details:
/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Myproject/Helloworld/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Myproject_Helloworld>
      <version>0.0.0.1</vresion>
    </Myproject_Helloworld>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <helloworld>
    <use>standard</use>
    <args>
      <module>Myproject_Helloworld</module>
      <frontName>helloworld</frontName>
    </args>
      </helloworld>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

/var/www/magento/app/etc/modules/Myproject_Helloworld.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Myproject_Helloworld>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Myproject_Helloworld>
  </modules>
</config>
```

/var/www/magento/app/code/local/Myproject/Helloworld/controllers/IndexController.php

```
<?php

class Myproject_Helloworld_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    echo 'Hello world!';
  }
}
?>
```

> I'm trying URL: [localhost/magento/helloworld/index/index](http://rami.local/magento/helloworld/index/index) Any idea
>   please .. thanx in advance.

Comment: try this: localhost/magento/index.phphelloworld/index/index

Comment: try localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld/index/index

Comment: please check in your config.xml <version>0.0.0.1</vresion> their is spelling mistake

Comment: thanx for quick respond .. I've tried the URL and still not working :(
appeared magento's requested page not foud
Help please ..

Comment: As @Pradeep Sanku said, there is a mistake in you xml file

Comment: still Can't find this mistake .. I'm using magento 1.8.1

Comment: @user4531 run xmllint on your xml file.

Answer (score 0):

First check in admin if your module works at all:

System->Configuration->Advanced

check if your module is listed. If it's not it means you have an error in your XML file (which you do)

you have

```
<version>0.0.0.1</vresion>
```

change it to

```
<version>0.0.0.1</version>
```

Comment: thank you .. but my module is listed in Disable Modules output

Comment: I made InexController.php file for another incomplete module .. then suddenly it worked out .. is there any relation to the problem I had?

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code in my localhost and it worked fine there. Since your module is enabled in config, the issue may due to cache problem. Go to system->cache management and there select all items and disable them. Then go to var->cache folder of your folder directory and clear the cache items.

Now go to your controller file. There you have added **?>** at the end. Please avoid it. If you check the core files in magento, you can see that, magento does not encourage the usage of 'closing php notation' (?>) for code pool files ( [core, community, local]  are the codepools of magento).

Now try to load your page.Probably it will work.Good luck

Comment: I made InexController.php file for another incomplete module .. then suddenly it worked out .. is there any relation to the problem I had?

Comment: your code working perfectly here. so your problem may due to cache problem.every time you need to clear cache. make sure,your indexcontroller.php file does not end with ?> sign. Also make sure it DOES start with <?php. if it doesnt work, try to change the version to 0.1.0 and just avoid xml specification(<?xml version='1.0'?>) from config and Myproject_Helloworld.xml. clear cache again and then try to load the page

Comment: which version of magento that you are using?

Comment: I'm using Magento ver. 1.8.1.0

Comment: I disabled caching before starting to build my module,removed ?> sign as you advised but didn't make a change for me, and didn't remove specification in xml files

Answer (score 0):

Wow .. suddenly worked ..
used this URL: localhost/magento/index.php/helloworld/index/index .. thanx all and good luck

Comment: I made InexController.php file for another incomplete module .. then suddenly it worked out .. is there any relation to the problem I had?